# Getting return value using .done after jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, return-value

I'm trying get the return value of an ajax post using jQuery. The return value should be a number (e.g. 2). Doing the post to the page directly gets me the correct answer, which is say, 2.

In the code below I'm trying to show the value 2 in an alert box but getting "object Object" instead...

```
function updatePositionDisplay(item)
{        
        var request = $.ajax('/admin/gallery/position', {
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'param=' + item
        });

        request.done(function(data) {
            alert(data);                
        });   
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here?

I have Googled and also searched this site but could not find a specific case to this. :(

Comment: Try alerting `data[0]` and see what you get.

Comment: Just tried, alerts "undefined". Hmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

you can try a `console.log(data)` instead of alert, so you can see whats inside the object.
second, pls tell us what the /position endpoint returns.

Comment: Your suggestion has helped me debug and find that the problem lies in /admin/gallery/position itself, where the value is not printed / echoed. Sorry that I could not vote your answer... not enough reputation points :(

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: The OP does not specify that there is JSON in the response. Are you just guessing?

Comment: yes, from what he gets, object Object, after seeing what the object has inside, OP can figure out to use its properties, probably 'data.responseText' is what he needs.

Comment: so you are telling that it is incorrect to print object with its properties using JSON.stringify, if the object is not JSON? :)

Comment: Incorrect? No. Bad practice? Yes. The `console.log()` is a better way of identifying what the Object is.

Comment: Hey guys, just found out that in **/admin/gallery/position** there was no echoing the value. Made the page print the value and voila! The intended numbers appear.

I really appreciate all your help even though it's my silly mistake. :)